# EF One To Many Bug

Tags: .net, entity-framework, one-to-many

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

When it gets to the db.SaveChanges() I get the following error.

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: EntityType 'Order' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Orders1: EntityType: EntitySet 'Orders1' is based on type 'Order' that has no keys defined.

As you can see I am not trying to do anything complex but, can't see what I have missed.

Db Context:

```
public class NewOrderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NewServices.OrderEntity> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewServices.OrderLineEntity> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

OrderEntity:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class OrderEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public decimal Handling { get; set; }
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddresseeName { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
    public string ShippingRegion { get; set; }
    public string ShippingCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShippingPostalCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string TrackingRef { get; set; }
    public int OfferId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLineEntity> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

OrderLineEntity:

```
[Table("OrderLine")]
public class OrderLineEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public decimal PartPrice { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the above in the following method snippet:

```
using (var db = new NewOrderContext())
{
    var order = new OrderEntity
                {
                    OfferId = offerId,
                    ....
                    Created = DateTime.UtcNow
                };


    var lines = new List<OrderLineEntity>
                {
                    new OrderLineEntity
                    {
                        PartCode = offer.PartCode,
                        PartPrice = offer.PriceOffered
                    }
                };

    order.OrderLines = lines;
    db.Orders.Add(order);
    db.SaveChanges();
 ......
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How is it not working the way you expected it to?

Comment: Good point!  When it gets to the db.SaveChanges() I get the following error.

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

EntityType 'Order' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Orders1: EntityType: EntitySet 'Orders1' is based on type 'Order' that has no keys defined.

Comment: @DazManCat  If you have a specific question or error information, please [edit] your question to include it.  As it stands there is no problem description here.

Comment: Ok, added the error to the question.

Comment: From design perspective, it makes little sense to expose `DbSet<OrderLine>` as each order line should be considered a value-object and can only be accessed/modified using its parent `Order`

Comment: It's seems like you just need to change `public virtual Order Order { get; set; }` to `public virtual OrderEntity Order { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes the exception does mention Order  which confuses me as within that context there are only the DBSets that I posted.

Comment: Ahhh yes!  There is a legacy object elsewhere in the code!  I referred to the wrong thing!